# Ajax Request Return HTML code inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking to use an ajax request to return and execute the html content from another page

The first page is basically just a page requesting the get.php page and displaying inside the div this works fine no issues

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function get_page(){
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/get.php',
   dataType: 'html'
  }).done(function( data ) {
  $('#get_page').html(data);
  });
}   
get_page();
</script>



<div id='get_page'></div>
```

the second page basicly just has a form on it i wish to be able to submit from the first page index.php however when submitting the form nothing happens is there a way to return the html code from get.php and insert it between `<div id='get_page'></div>` so that when browsing the source code i can see it between the div or how can i submit the form on the get.php from index.php

get.php

```
<form action='index.php'>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_fname' required>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_lname' required>
<input type='submit' value='Save' >
</form>
```

Please bare in mind I'm semi new to ajax and javascript and if possible please provide an example for your answers.

Comment: Sorry small over-site edited now

Comment: what do you get if in the `.done` function you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: it loads the html content into the console but doesn't allow to be submitted

Comment: can you copy paste here what's in your console?

Comment: If you want to submit your form to `get.php`, then your action should be get.php instead of `index.php`. And if you want to use ajax you need to handle it on the click of submit button.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the action is it still doesn't submit the form

Comment: @Nathan How are you checking whether the form has submitted or not?

Comment: @Nathan You should get the values in $_GET variable try this on index.php `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using PHP, why don't you use the php include?

```
<div id='get_page'>
   <?php include 'get.php';?>
</div>
```

or you can add it in an `<iframe>` element then use jquery's `.html()` to append it to the div you want

```
<iframe src="get.php">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I should also mention that using iframes is frowned upon in HTML5

Comment: I have looked at these 2 options and I wish to use the Ajax method

Comment: Your ajax seems fine to me as is. do you get any console errors?? does your ajax call succeed in getting the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_fname' required>
 <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_lname' required>
 <input type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

Comment: Default method is GET so I dont think thats the issue.

Comment: You should explain something in your answer, because things that are obvious to you  might not be obvious to others